# UINavigationController not showing a Next button when viewcontrollers are set programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

In a prepareForSegue method I am modally pushing a UINavigationController.  I set the viewControllers array for the UINavigation controller with an array of viewcontrollers that is populated in a custom object based on a custom initalizer.  Initially, I got the UINavigationController with all the UIViewContorllers BUT the UINavigationConotrller STARTED at the last viewcontroller in the array, having only a back button.  I added the popToRootViewControllerAnimated line and now the UINavigationController starts at the first UIViewController but dosen't have a next button?  How do I get the Next Button to appear in the NavigationBar to navigate through the viewcontrollers?

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

NSNumber *switchOn = [NSNumber numberWithBool:self.blueSwitch.on];

PBVslideViews *slideViews = [[PBVslideViews alloc] initWithQuestionareResults:switchOn];
PBVpressentationNavigation *slides = (PBVpressentationNavigation  
*)segue.destinationViewController;
[slides setViewControllers:slideViews.slideViews animated:YES];
[slides popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "next" button for `UINavigationController`s.

A `UINavigationController` maintains a stack of controllers, not an array. When you push many controllers onto the stack you see the top one. When you call `-popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` it removes all the controllers above the root controller leaving only a single controller on the stack.

You can add your own "next" button and push controllers onto the stack as needed but that sort of interface seems likely to confuse iOS users.

---

Take a look at the [iOS HIG Navigation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Navigation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH53-SW1) section for alternatives:

> Use a navigation bar to give users an easy way to traverse a hierarchy of data.
>
> ...
>
> Use a tab bar to display several peer categories of content or functionality.
>
> ...
>
> Use a page control when each app screen represents an individual instance of the same type of item or page.

Which is actually a good fit for the information you are displaying?

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  After studying the situation a little I see this is exactly correct, leveraging a tab bar here works much better and is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in functionality for a Next button on UINavigationController, you must add the button to your navigation item in each view controller and make it's action create and push a new view controller on to the navigation stack. When you call `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` you have popped all of your other view controllers (besides the root) off of the stack and they have likely been deallocated and are no longer in the `viewControllers` array on your navigation controller. That is why you are only seeing the root, but even if the others did still exist, you would have to create a button titled "Next" who calls a method that creates a new view controller and pushes it.